# no suitable conversion function from "std::string" to "PVOID" exists

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to use the SetParametersInfo function to change wallpapers.I would like to pass the filepath for the wallpaper as a variable, but whenever I try to do this, I get the error

```
Error: no suitable conversion function from "std::string" to "PVOID" exists
```

Here is the code I have thus far

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")
using namespace std;

#define _TEXT(x) L##x

void main(){
    string input ="";
    cout << "Enter the filepath\n";
    getline(cin, input);

    BOOL success = SystemParametersInfo(
    SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER,   //iuAction
    0,                      //uiParam
    input,                  //pvParam
    SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE      //fWinIni
    );
    if (success){
        printf("Success!\n");
    }else
        printf("Failure =(\n");
}
```

Do you guys have any suggestions for what I can do? I have looked all over to find a solution and haven't been able to find one. Perhaps I am not searching for the right terms.

Extra info: I am running Windows 7 and using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate.

**Edit:**
I finally got it to work. I had to change the "Character Set" setting to "Not Set" then it worked fine. Here is the updated code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")
using namespace std;

void main(){
    string input ="";
    cout << "Enter the filepath\n";
    getline(cin, input);

    BOOL success = SystemParametersInfo(
    SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER,   //iuAction
    0,                      //uiParam
    (PVOID) input.c_str(),  //pvParam
    SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE      //fWinIni
    );
    if (success){
        printf("Success!\n");
    }else{
        printf("Failure =(\n ");
        cout << input << "\n";
        cout << (PVOID) input.c_str()<< "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Same problem you got last time, the pvParam argument is of type void*.  This time there is no standard conversion from std::string to void*.  And using string::c_str() gets you the same problem back again, it isn't a Unicode string like std::wstring.

Comment: I see what you are trying to say I think, but before I was able to add the L to the beginning of the string literal (ie, L"C:/test.jpg"). I don't know how to do this when I am dealing with a variable instead of a literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

input.c_str() will return a const char * that will implicitly convert to PVOID.

Pass input.c_str() to SystemParametersInfo and it should work.

*Make sure this is not compiled with UNICODE=1 because then SystemParametersInfo is redirected to SystemParametersInfoW which would expect a std::wstring, not a std::string.

If you really want to force an ascii string even when compiling UNICODE then call SystemParametersInfoA explicitly.

Comment: When I try to pass input.c_str(), I get the error "Error: argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "PVOID""

Comment: You have to manually cast because `void *` (which is the same as `PVOID`) loses the `const`-ness of `const char *`. `(PVOID)(input.c_str())` ought to do it.

Comment: ok, I have changed it to be (PVOID)(input.c_str()) and it compiles, but always fails. I have added code to print the values of input and (PVOID)input.c_str(). For the input C:/test.jpg, input is C:/test.jpg and (PVOID)input.c_str() is 0017FDDC. Do you have any idea why the function is failing?

Comment: did you change it to SystemParametersInfoA (add the character 'A' to the end of the function name.)

Answer (score 0):

```
BOOL success = SystemParametersInfo(
SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER,   //iuAction
0,                      //uiParam
(PVOID)input.c_str(),   //pvParam
SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE      //fWinIni
);
```

Comment: ok, I have changed it to be (PVOID)(input.c_str()) and it compiles, but always fails. I have added code to print the values of input and (PVOID)input.c_str(). For the input C:/test.jpg, input is C:/test.jpg and (PVOID)input.c_str() is 0017FDDC. Do you have any idea why the function is failing?

Answer (score 0):

string::c_str() will return a const char* pointer, then you may need to do a pointer type cast to make the SystemParametersInfo works.

```
BOOL success = SystemParametersInfo(
SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER,   //iuAction
0,                      //uiParam
(PVOID)input.c_str(),                  //pvParam
SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE      //fWinIni
);
```